# How to close a Flutter program on crashing like in Android? Currently the app just shows a debugBanner

Tags: flutter, dart

In Android the app closes just after the crash and a dialogBox is shown stating that the app has crashed. I want a similar behaviour in flutter app, i.e it should stop and app should get killed once it has crashed but rather than that it shows a debugBanner although I have turned it off by using

```
 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
```

Answer (score 0):

That's for debugging purpose. If you want to run as release version.

`$ flutter run --release`

read more about modes
https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes